# Property title does not exist on type string in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework Right now i am trying to fetch data,I am fetching data but i am also getting error `"Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'"`,how can i fix this ? Here is my current code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
export default function Test() {
  const [data, setData] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    const callData = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/10').then(data => data.json())
      console.log(data);
      setData(data)
    }
    callData()
  }, [])

  return (
    
    data === '' ? <>loading ... </> : <div>{data.title}</div>
    )

}
```

Comment: make your call to callData() have an await otherwise you are having synchronization issues.

Comment: @MacroSacramento can you update/post the exact answer so i can check/learn and can implement at my side

Comment: @MacroSacramento: No, `useEffect` *should not* return a `Promise`.  The asynchronous operation shown is already correct.  Though it can be improved by replacing the `.then()` operation with a second `await`, since mixing callbacks and awaits can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a string:

```
const [data, setData] = useState('')
```

And looking for a property on it called `title`:

```
<div>{data.title}</div>
```

There is indeed no such property on a string, which is what TypeScript (not JavaScript) is telling you.  Instead of using an empty string to indicate a lack of value, use `undefined`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

And modify the usage to check for "falsy" values:

```
return (
  data ? <div>{data.title}</div> : <>loading ... </>
);
```

Since you're using TypeScript, you'll probably also want to start specifying the types for these values.  The `useState` call can include a type specifier, as well as the AJAX operation(s).  Otherwise you're relying on implicit `any` types, at which point there's little reason to be using TypeScript at all.

For example, even with the above code you *may* still need to specify a type:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<{title:string}>();
```

Otherwise it may be looking for the property `title` on the implied type `never`, which also won't work.  The above type I'm using is anonymous, based on the only information we have in the question (the presence of a property called `title`).  If you have a named type, such as a defined interface, that would be ideal.

You *could* get away with an explicit `any` type:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<any>();
```

But at that point why use TypeScript at all?  There's no reason to use a static typing system just to tell it not to worry about static typing.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: @Jennie: I suspect the error has *slightly* changed, now referring to type `never` instead of type `string`.  I've updated the answer with an example of how to specify a type for `data`.  Ultimately, if you're using TypeScript then you should be using TypeScript to explicitly specify and control the types.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , kindly tell me one thing , how can i use "map function" ( want to fetch data using loop)

Comment: @Jennie: For general documentation and examples, you can always reference the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map